# In NodeJS express; How can I get form properties from a form post?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, body-parser

node -v
v10.15.0

I have multiple standard forms on a page loaded via AJAX (so I don't know how many or where from). Each has a form name.

I want to get the form attributes but they are not returned in the req.body variable.

In the example below I want to access the form name as form1. I have looked at the req object but cannot find a description of the form that has been submitted.

How can I get the form attributes such as name and method and action? Do I need to do something to the in built body parser?

Example is:

```
<form method='post' name='form1'>
       <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

On the node express side I have the following:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log(req.body);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Console shows {}

I don't think this is a repeat question. Spent an hour or so searching for this answer.

Comment: Did you use `bodyparser` middleware?? Can you post your server.js code??

Comment: I am pretty sure it's built in now. I had previously used // var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// app.use(bodyParser()); Perhaps it's the app.use(express.json()); line?

Comment: This explains what I have done - https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the form attributes such as name and method and action? Do I need to do something to the in built body parser?

No, only form elements designed to contain data in the form are sent automatically with the form post.  Attributes of the parent `form` element such as `name` and `action` are not sent.

A trick that is often used in forms it to insert a hidden element in the form (one that the user does not see) and put data into that element that you want sent to the server.  Then the server can access the data like any other named form element.  You can either populate those elements when the form is originally designed or you can populate them dynamically with Javascript at any time before the form is submitted.

For example:

```
 <form method='post' name='form1' action="/form1Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="form1">
    Enter your data here: <input name="data">
    <input type='submit'>
 </form>
```

Assuming your have the body-parser middleware appropriately configured, then when this form is submitted you will be able to access `req.body.action` and `req.body.formName` and `req.body.data` in your express server.

Comment: Yeah I did that as a work around but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Daz - It may not be what you're looking for, but my first paragraph answers your question.  The browser does not automatically send the attributes you asked for.  You have to insert that data into something (some other way) that the browser does send.  Whether it's what you wanted or not, you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it's not answered. I want to get the attributes of the form object from my POST. You have only said it can't be done and provided an obvious work around. Perhaps someone else can answer it by advising what I need to do. For example what changes need to be made to the body parser to include the information I am seeking.

Comment: @Daz - The information you want is NOT sent from the browser to the server.  The body-parser runs only only the server and thus has NO access to that data.  That data does not exist on the server.  It was not sent to the server.  You have to change something in the client to cause the data to be sent.  You asked "can I do X".  The answer is "NO".  The data does not exist on the server.  Nothing you do on the server can make the data appear.  You have to change the client so that it actually sends that data in something that is sent with a posted form.

Comment: Ok. Are you saying that HTTP POST does not send that data when it posts?

Comment: @Daz - I'm saying that the browser does not include the `<form>` tag attributes as part of a browser submitted HTTP POST.  The data is simply not sent to the server.  You can use the Network tab in the Chrome debugger and look at exactly what the browser sends to the server on your form post.  You will have to click the [X] Preserve Log checkbox in the Network tab so the data you want to see isn't wiped out after the form post succeeds.